# Rotate list <li> of images placed on a circle on click of any child to a given position

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-animations

I have arranged a list of images on a circle using css transforms. what i want is that when any child image of the list is clicked the circle rotates and the selected or the active child image reaches to a given position. say 3'o clock.
how can i achieve this with js. i dont know sass currently

this is what i got right now.

!https://ibb.co/zfPQvNn

when any child image is clicked i want the circle to rotate such that the active image always ends up at the same position. say 3'o clock

```html
<div class="team-list">
    <ul>
       <li class="wow active zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".1s">
            <a href="#team-1" data-team="team-1">
               <figure>
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image One">
               </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
            <a href="#team-2" data-team="team-2">
               <figure>
                       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image two">
               </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <a href="#team-3" data-team="team-3">
               <figure>
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image three">
              </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".7s">
            <a href="#team-4" data-team="team-4">
               <figure>
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image four">
               </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".9s">
            <a href="#team-5" data-team="team-5">
               <figure>
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image five">
              </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.1s">
            <a href="#team-6" data-team="team-6">
               <figure>
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image six">
               </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.3s">
            <a href="#team-7" data-team="team-7">
               <figure>
                       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image seven">
               </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.5s">
            <a href="#team-8" data-team="team-8">
               <figure>
                       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/" alt="Team Member image eight">
               </figure>
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>      
</div>
```

```css
.team-list > ul > * {
  /* 4 */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:55%;

}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
}
.team-list >ul > :nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10em) rotate(-45deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10em) rotate(-90deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(10em) rotate(-135deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(10em) rotate(-225deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10em) rotate(-270deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(10em) rotate(-315deg);
}

.team-list img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: in case i am unclear because i am new to this community https://ibb.co/tPjSHZC this is what i want done

Comment: Hey! Welcome to the Stackoverflow community; be sure to tell us what all you have tried till now and we can help you resolve your problems. :)

Comment: one way to go about with this would be to keep the css the same and change the order of the list so that the selected child stays on the top to get positioned at 3'o clock but i couldnt find a way to try this out. the other would be to rotate each image on click to the desired position but that would be a rather bad approach.

Comment: What about absolute positions? Have you tried doing that?

Comment: yes but the transition wouldn't seem circular and i couldnt sync the animation well

Comment: hello, is the amount of items gonna be fixed? always 8? or could it increase/decrease dynamically?

Comment: it's going to be fixed for this thing i am working on...so a solution for 8 would be really helpful although a solution for any n no. of items would help everyone else as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

One of the ways it could be done is by "transferring" the *transform* property across the items every time a user clicks one, achieving an effect somewhat attractive but not quite a clean rotation. You would do this by using the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function, like this:

```js
let allItems = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName('li');
let allItemsAsArray = Array.from(allItems);

let fixedPositions = {}, transforms = {};
let auxPosition = 0;

allItemsAsArray.forEach((elem, index) => {
  transforms[auxPosition] = window.getComputedStyle(elem).transform;
  fixedPositions[index] = auxPosition++;

  elem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let steps = 8 - fixedPositions[index];
    allItemsAsArray.forEach((elem2, index2) => {
          copyTransformProp(
              transforms[fixedPositions[(index2 + steps) % 8]]
            ,
          elem2);
    });
  });
});

function copyTransformProp(sourceProperty, targetNode) {  
  targetNode.style.setProperty('transform', sourceProperty);
}
```

```css
.team-list > ul > li {
  /* 4 */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:55%;
  left: 40%;
  transition: ease all 1s;
}

#list img {
  width: 50px
}

.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
}

.team-list >ul > :nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10em) rotate(-45deg);
}

.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(10em) rotate(-135deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(10em) rotate(-225deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10em) rotate(-270deg);
}
.team-list > ul > :nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(10em) rotate(-315deg);
}

.team-list img {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-list">
    <ul id='list'>
       <li class="wow active zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".1s" >
            <a href="#team-1" data-team="team-1">
               
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=1" alt="Team Member image One">
               
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
            <a href="#team-2" data-team="team-2">
               
                       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=2" alt="Team Member image two">
               
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
            <a href="#team-3" data-team="team-3">
               
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=3" alt="Team Member image three">
              
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".7s">
            <a href="#team-4" data-team="team-4">
               
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=4" alt="Team Member image four">
               
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".9s">
            <a href="#team-5" data-team="team-5">
               
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=5" alt="Team Member image five">
              
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.1s">
            <a href="#team-6" data-team="team-6">
               
                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=6" alt="Team Member image six">
               
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.3s">
            <a href="#team-7" data-team="team-7">
               
                       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=7" alt="Team Member image seven">
               
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.5s">
            <a href="#team-8" data-team="team-8">
               
                       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=8" alt="Team Member image eight">
               
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>      
</div>
```

### Option 2

Now, to achieve a really clean rotation, I would go with [request​Animation​Frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
. This time you would not depend on the CSS property *transition* for smoothness, but directly in JavaScript, working with angles.

I thought it might be better to generate the items dynamically in JS, so you don't have to style each one manually in CSS. It also allows you to generate "as many items as you want", careful though, don't get too greedy on the amount.

Try this snippet full page.

HIH

```js
let ul = document.getElementById('list');
let anglePerItem = [];

generateItems(8, 0, 9);

let allItems = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
let allItemsAsArray = Array.from(allItems);

function generateItems(itemNum, initAngle, radius) {
    let angleStep = Math.PI * 2 / itemNum;
    let angle = initAngle;

    for (let i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        if (i === 0)
            li.classList.add('wow', 'active', 'zoomIn');
        else
            li.classList.add('wow', 'zoomIn');

        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = '#team-' + (i + 1);
        a.setAttribute('data-team', 'team-' + (i + 1));
        li.appendChild(a);

        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/&text=' + (i + 1);
        img.alt = 'Team Member image ' + (i + 1);
        a.appendChild(img);

        let x = Math.cos(angle) * radius, y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
        anglePerItem.push(angle);
        angle += angleStep;
        li.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'em, ' + y + 'em)';

        ul.appendChild(li);

        addClickEvent(li, i, radius);
    }
}

function addClickEvent(elem, clickedIndex, radius) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (anglePerItem[clickedIndex] !== 0) {
            Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName('li')).forEach((elem, index) => {
                let angle = anglePerItem[index] % (Math.PI * 2);
                let endAngle = Math.PI * 2 - anglePerItem[clickedIndex] + angle;
                if (angle > endAngle)
                    endAngle += Math.PI * 2;

                function step(timestamp) {
                    let x = Math.cos(angle) * radius, y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
                    angle += .1;

                    elem.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'em, ' + y + 'em)';

                    if (angle < endAngle) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
                        }, 10);
                    } else {
                        elem.style.transform = 'translate(' + Math.cos(endAngle) * radius + 'em, ' + Math.sin(endAngle) * radius + 'em)';
                        anglePerItem[index] = endAngle;
                    }
                }

                window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.team-list > ul > li {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 40%;
}

#list img {
    width: 50px
}

.team-list img {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-list"><ul id='list'></ul></div>
```

Comment: thank you. these solutions worked perfectly but i personally liked the transition in option 1. you the best buddy!